# How to Retrieve Values Resulting From AJAX Live Search?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Below is a jQuery function that retrieves 2 textbox values and posts them to another file ("Student Search Results.php"), where a live search is run using the values.

```
<script>
    $(".search").keyup(function() {
        var Team_Name = $('#TeamName').val();
        var Teacher = $('#Teacher').val();
        var Search_Data = Team_Name + '?????' + Teacher;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Student Search Results.php",
            data: {
                query: Search_Data
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function() {
                alert('The values were sent');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Below is the PHP script on the search page ("Student Search Results.php") that makes use of these values.

```
<?php

include "Connection.php";

    if(isset($_POST['query'])){

        $searchData = explode('?????', $_POST['query']);

        $teamName = $searchData[0];
        $teacher = $searchData[1];

        $query = "SELECT club_table.Club_Name, teacher_user_table.Teacher_Name
            FROM club_table, teacher_user_table
            WHERE club_table.Teacher_Email = teacher_user_table.Teacher_Email,
            teacher_user_table.Teacher_Name LIKE '%" . $teacher . "%', 
            club_table.Club_Name LIKE '%" . $teamName . "%';";

    }else{

     $query = "SELECT club_table.Club_Name, teacher_user_table.Teacher_Name
            FROM club_table, teacher_user_table
            WHERE club_table.Teacher_Email = teacher_user_table.Teacher_Email;";

    }

     $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);   
     echo $query;

?>
```

How would I be able to take variables from the PHP script (such as $result) to the first page, so I can create a result table? Simply including the PHP file does not work, as the file is only included once.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Best option is to serialize to JSON using [`json_encode`](https://www.php.net/json_encode)

Answer (score 0):

I think best you can do is,

```
   success: function(result) {
            alert(result);
        }
```

and `Student Search Results.php` print result in tabular format.

**P.S. : Please follow proper file naming convention**

Answer (score 0):

use a proper URL, and send the data (and stop using camelcase for everything) :

```
$(".search").on('keyup', function() {
    var data = {
         team_name : $('#TeamName').val(),
         teacher   : $('#Teacher').val()
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "student_search_results.php",
        data: data,
        cache: false
    }).done(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```

And in PHP, you have to actually get the result into an array and json_encode it :

```
<?php
    include "Connection.php";

    $team_name = !empty( $_POST['team_name'] ) ? $_POST['team_name'] : null;
    $teacher   = !empty( $_POST['teacher'] ) ? $_POST['teacher'] : null;

    if ($team_name && $teacher) {
        $query = "SELECT club_table.Club_Name, teacher_user_table.Teacher_Name
            FROM club_table, teacher_user_table
            WHERE club_table.Teacher_Email = teacher_user_table.Teacher_Email,
            teacher_user_table.Teacher_Name LIKE '%" . $teacher . "%', 
            club_table.Club_Name LIKE '%" . $teamName . "%';";
    }else{
         $query = "SELECT club_table.Club_Name, teacher_user_table.Teacher_Name
            FROM club_table, teacher_user_table
            WHERE club_table.Teacher_Email = teacher_user_table.Teacher_Email;";
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);   
    $data = $result->fetch_all( MYSQLI_ASSOC );

    echo json_encode( $data );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $(".search").keyup(function() {
        var Team_Name = $('#TeamName').val();
        var Teacher = $('#Teacher').val();
        var Search_Data = "Team_Name="+'Team_Name'&Teacher='+Teacher;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Student_Search_Results.php",
            data: Search_Data,
            cache: false,
            success: function(result) {
                $('$output').html(result);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

> Here is output div

```
<div id="output"></div>
```

On `Student_Search_Results.php` page get

```
$tname = $_POST['Team_Name'];
$teacher = $_POST['Teacher'];
```

> //your search query & print data